# Crear programa que se ejecute en escritorio y a la vez se pueda ejecutar como applet

Tags: java

Buenas, tengo que hacer un programa que se puede ejecutar tanto en escritorio como en applet, usando mvc. La cuestion es que no se como atacar al programa...
Debo crear el main, en el instanciar el constructor, y a la vez crear una clase que extienda de applet en el que tambien se instancia el constructor, y en funcion de si se ejecuta en escritorio o en el navegador arranque por un sitio o por otro?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- El comando [appletviewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) permite ejecutar un applet como aplicación de escritorio.
- Crear dos versiones del programa. No es tán complicado como pareces si organizas bien el programa (la lógica separada de la presentación); tienes tanto una clase que implementa `Applet` como una clase con el `main` que lanza el GUI; las dos simplemente llaman a las mismas clases que serán las que tengan la funcionalidad ("la chicha") del programa. Como de todas formas tienes que indicar qué clase ejecutas, puedes tener ambas clases en el mismo proyecto.

  Una cuestión importante a tener en cuenta es que, a menos que lo firmes adecuadamente, un applet tendrá importantes restricciones de seguridad a la hora de ejecutarse.

Una tercera opción que no es exactamente lo que pides pero que puede ayudar es Java Web Start, puedes buscarlo para ver si te sirve.

Comment: Al final di con la solucion, y es algo parecido a lo que comentas en el segundo punto. Para cuando se vaya a ejecutar en el navegador, simplemente el navegador llamara a la clase applet y list.

Comment: Le di al intro sin querer jajaja. Para ejecutarlo en escritorio, simplemente cree un frame, y como applet extiende de panel, pues se lo añadi al frame y listo.

Answer (score 1):

Para no crear dos versiones el concepto que buscas se llama Entry-Point.
Considera que son dos problemas diferentes:

1. la distribución (y en consecuencia la actualización) del
   programa.
2. el lanzamiento del programa.

Si la distribución no es un problema (es decir, no tienes inconveniente en andar rolando un archivo jar mediante correo o memorias USB) el truco más simple para escritorio está en el Manifest del jar (Main-Class).

JNLP abarca tanto distribución como lanzamiento para escritorio y web.